# Authentication failed when check out a private project of Gitlab in android studio

Tags: git, android-studio, gitlab

We have a private project in Gitlab that I am member of that and have Administrator access to that.

But at first checkout (check out project from version control) I enter incorrect username in, the problem is that I cannot change my Gitlab account identification in android studio. And cannot access none of my project stored in Gitlab.
Can anybody help about that to solve this problem?

Comment: I also encountered this problem and changing system setting >>password >>and checking "Do not save ,... " did not solve my problem.

Comment: What are you using to clone https or ssh?

Comment: Iam using https.

Comment: I think here is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382950
It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just copy git scm to your programfiles and do not install it,then execute bash from it.
if authentication not pass yet,you should install certificate files in 
Program Files>>Git>>mingw64>>ssl>>certs

Comment: Good solution bro!

Answer (score 2):

If you had installed Git in your system, try to remove it.
It should help you!